# retrieve a column value using foreign key id in another table

Tags: database, laravel-5

I have this function written in controller

```
public function collector_second()
    {


      $collectors=DB::table('collections')->where('collector_id', '=', 2)->get();

      return View::make('users.collector', compact('collectors',$collectors));


    }
```

In the collections table  I have record_id which is a foreign key of records table. And I have this foreach loop in blade template

```
 @foreach($collectors as $collector)


                 <td>{{$collector->record_id}}</td>

 @endforeach
```

Insted of displaying the record_id in the table I want the user_name from records table. I have my relation in both the model

```
class Record extends Model
{

    public function collections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Collection');
    }
}



   class Collection extends Model
{
     public function records()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Record');
    }
}
```

How can I get this right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using query builder

```
public function collector_second()
{


      $collectors = DB::table('collections')
           ->join('records','records.id','=','collections.record_id')
           ->where('collector_id', '=', 2)
           ->select('records.*)
           ->get();

      return View::make('users.collector', compact('collectors',$collectors));


}
```

This will simply select all records by joining on collection.